# How to use a case study in a literature review?

Tags: citations, literature-review

I am writing a literature review and I may need to include three case studies. What is the best way to go about it? Am I allowed to include the whole case study for the reader's review and then analyze the points made?

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'include the whole case study'?

Comment: To copy and paste it as it is, word for word. Then reference it.

Comment: I don't know about your field, but in mine, case studies are full-length articles. These you couldn't cite verbatim from beginning to end.

Comment: Noted with thanks! For clarity, I'm looking to use mini-case studies which are not that long. Hence why i am using three.
But I do see your point.

Comment: Why would you include a case study in your literature review?

Comment: I am by no means a master when it comes to research work so maybe it's not common/acceptable to use case studies in literature reviews. Please let me know if this is the case.

But I feel that it is a source of material that can be used to perfectly illustrate how a problem exists in the real world with an example.

The case study does this and gives perspective on what still needs to be done in future to address the problem better. This is why I have included them.